# Edit Duplicated MovieClip Affects The Original -- Flash CS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, movieclip

I have a MovieClip that contains tabs and buttons, I want to create a similar one but with different structure (another types of button and tabs), I want to use the work that was done with the first one so I duplicate it, the problem is when I edit the second MovieClip (delete tabs and buttons), the first one changes too, it's like they're linked somehow, is there a way to fix that.

I'm using Flash CS 5 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behavior, a single `MovieClip` symbol can have multiple instances; all instances have the same content.

If you want to create a copy of your `MovieClip` as a new symbol, go to the `Library` select the desired `MovieClip` and right click on it and select `Duplicate...` or simply right click in the `MovieClip` at the scene and select `Duplicate Symbol...`, then you can drag the duplicated symbol from `Library` to the scene.

Now, you need to know that every symbol inside this copy share the same reference with the other ones in the original `MovieClip` so if you want to modify those symbols you need to do the same procedure.

Comment: "multiple `MovieClips` can share the same instance" -- to be clear: multiple *instances* can share the same source *symbol*. This is what makes it an "instance" of a symbol. Changes to the instance (position, scale, effects) are never shared with other instances.

Comment: Please @Aaron can you fix any mistake that I have commited?
My english is not very good, feel free to change any mistake or mistranslated word and let your username in the edition.
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Ok, made a small edit. :) PS - I thought your English was very good, I didn't guess it wasn't your first language.

Comment: Wow, thanks :) I'm an eternal english student, but I speak like a cow, I try to learn every day.